# Plotting a conference interval on a poisson glm (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have a poisson glm and i am trying to plot 95% condidence intervals using ggplot. My issue lies when i use the geom_ribbon() argument. I think my model and CIs are all set up fine, its just the ggplot code that i cannot get to work, if anyone knows what ive done wrong in the geom_ribbon argument this could be great

model, CIs and plot code

```
#creating the poisson GLM model
model3 = glm(cases ~ date,
         data = aids,
         family = poisson(link='log'))



#make predictions
model3_preds = predict(model3, type = 'response')

#create predictions for confidence intervals
predictions_model3 = predict(model3, aids, se.fit = TRUE, type = 'response')

#calculate 95% confidence intervals limit
upper_mod3 = predictions_model3$fit+1.96*predictions_model3$se.fit 
lower_mod3 = predictions_model3$fit-1.96*predictions_model3$se.fit

#combining our predictions and confidence intervals into a df
predframe_model3 = data.frame(lwr = lower_mod3, upr = upper_mod3, data = aids$date, cases = aids$cases)

#plotting our model with 95% confidence intervals around the mean
ggplot(aids, aes(date, cases)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = predframe_model3, aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = 'grey') +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(date, model3_preds), col = 'red')
```

aids data snipet if needed

```
aids
cases quarter  date
 1      2       1 83.00
 2      6       2 83.25
 3     10       3 83.50
 4      8       4 83.75
 5     12       1 84.00
 6      9       2 84.25
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can plot directly with ggplot without a prediction data frame, using `geom_smooth`:

```r
ggplot(aids, aes(date, cases)) +
  geom_smooth(method = glm, formula = y ~ x, color = "red",
              method.args = list(family = poisson)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, although I need to do it the way I was using with geom_line() and geom_ribbon(). Sorry should have made that clear in the question

Comment: In that case @Joe, your problem seems to be just a typo. You have called the `date` variable `data` in `predframe_model3`. If you change that, you will get a working (but less smooth) plot.

Comment: Brill, knew i just needed a fresh pair of eyes